# ERROR:: R8: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: continuous-integration, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, android-r8

We are working on a project which includes lot of new code being developed in terms of multiple sdk's (Being developed in-house) and when we started integrating the new code changes coming along with the sdk's developed by the teams we are getting below error:

```
minifyReleaseWithR8
WARNING:: R8: Missing class: org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier
WARNING:: R8: Missing class: com.bun.miitmdid.interfaces.IIdentifierListener
ERROR:: R8: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

**The thing to be noted is this is happening while creating build from our CI pipeline and works perfectly on our local machines**. Have visited multiple posts mentioning the changes to be done in jvm memory options. Below are the properties we have defined in "gradle.properties" and "build.gradle".

## Gradle daemon config

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

We have tried all the combinations by increasing and decreasing the values for "org.gradle.jvmargs" and  "MaxPermSize" but no success.

```
android {
    //Other configs
    dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
```

We have even tried increasing the CI runner configration from 8GB RAM to 16GB RAM (4core) but still no success.

Comment: Running R8 on large inputs can require a large heap space. Normally 16GB should be sufficient, and `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` should work. Are you using a different configuration locally vs. on CI? One option is to try to run without a Gradle Daemin on CI (running the Gradle build with `--no-daemon`). You could also try to add `-verbose:gc`, to `org.gradle.jvmargs` see how the java VM GC progresses.

Comment: @sgjesse tried both "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" and "--no-daemon" but its not working. Any idea why ?

Comment: Could it be that the CI machines does not have that much memory, so raising it does not matter? Try to add `-Xms16G`, as that should allocate the 16 GB up front. Did you try `-verbose:gc`, as that should also log the amount of memory used for each GC.